# How do I compile Free Pascal on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: makefile, compilation, arm, pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to cross-compile some pascal project into an ARM *.so file. The compilation succeeds but when I try and load the *.so (e.g. using Python's `ctypes.CDLL()` function) I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $762340BC:
EStackOverflow: Stack overflow
    $762340BC
```

To avoid any cross-compilation issues I tried setting up everything on RPi directly. My fear is however that I still messed up somewhere. I spent several days trying to find help, but non joy. The project at hand is:

If you have a RPi at hand and want to give it a go try my repo here:

[https://github.com/Muxelmann/OpenDSSDirect.make](https://github.com/Muxelmann/OpenDSSDirect.make/tree/develop) (develop branch)

The `make setup` identifies your RPi and downloads all libraries and the Free Pascal Compiler (FPC) v3.0.2. `make` then downloads the code and compiles it. And the output in question is stored in `source/lib/xx/libopendssdirect.so` - I cannot load it.

Thank you for your help and/or advice.

Comment: Try to compile your project without stackchecking defined in compiler properties dialog

Comment: I dropped `-Ct` and now I get a `EInOutError: Invalid input` :/ I'll try other stack directives too! Thanks for the tip :)